# Using Sumproduct with ranges and cell references

Tags: excel

I am attempting to use `sumproduct` in replace of sumifs so I can use multiple criteria within a single range.  What works so far is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table2[Sum of MKTValue],--ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table2[Code],{"EG1","EG2"},0)),--ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table2[Currency],{"GBP","USD","EUR"},0)),(Table2[Final Date]=INDIRECT("J"&SUM(ROW()-102)))*1)
```

However I need the "J" column reference, when I attempt to drive this using the current column as below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table2[Sum of MKTValue],--ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table2[Code],{"EG1","EG2"},0)),--ISNUMBER(MATCH(Table2[Currency],{"GBP","USD","EUR"},0)),(Table2[Final Date]=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&SUM(ROW()-102)))*1)
```

Then I am getting a `#VALUE` error.  I have tried a number of different varieties of the above but I cannot get it to work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `Jn` contains a valid date - try moving the `SUM` function to outside `INDIRECT`, i.e. with last criterion

`(Table2[Final Date]=SUM(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")&ROW()-102))*1`

Comment: It does contain a valid date.  

That seems to have worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem.....although if the INDIRECT function gives you J8, for example, could you not use just J8 in the formula? That will still change to J9 or K8 as you copy down or across